# How to combine Max and Average in Power BI with Filters

Tags: powerbi, filtering

I want to create a measure (Average Late) in powerBI that calculates the Maximum of Late per Ordernumber, sum them up &  divide the by the number of orders.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tvJQ.png)

I also want this measure to be dynamic and only calculate whats displayed with filters.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqOGa.png)

I have tried with functions such as CALCULATE, MAX, DISTINCT & SUM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Measure =
VAR distinct_ordernumber =
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[OrderNumber] )
VAR sum_max_late_per_ordernumber =
    SUMX (
        SUMMARIZE ( 'Table'; 'Table'[OrderNumber]; "max_late"; MAX ( 'Table'[Late] ) );
        [max_late]
    )
RETURN
    FORMAT ( sum_max_late_per_ordernumber / distinct_ordernumber; "##.00" )
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.
I missed a thing in my question though..

I want to be able to visulize the result in a column chart, divided by weeks for example, therefore I need a Calculated column, not a measure.
Is there a simple solution for that? :)

Comment: @FredrikCederth not really following (also I am not able to open the second photo link in your question)? But if you add a date column on the column chart axis and the measure as value, this should be fine.

Comment: It's solved now, I changed the format back to numeric and then it worked of course. Thank you so much!